# How to disable automatic tab insertion?

Tags: notepad++

As I type away in Notepad++, on entering a newline tabs and spaces are inserted to line up the text below the start of the previous line.

Personally, I find this to be a pain, and I am wondering how to stop this from happening. The thread [at the Notepad++ Community Website](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/10946/how-to-avoid-insertion-of-tab/2) has a couple of suggestions:-

```
Settings->Preferences->MISC Turn off auto-indent
```

but this option doesn't appear to exist...

[Misc options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prRm2.png)

It also suggests

```
Settings->Tab Options
```

but as can be seen in the illustration, that doesn't exist either.

Is there any way to disable this particular feature so that what I type in is what I get (I am using version 7.9.5 and it doesn't appear to want to upgrade itself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uncheck `Auto-indent` in Settings >> preferences >> Auto-completion

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the Auto-Ident box in the following pad

Setting > Preferences > Auto-Completion

There is a selected box Auto-Ident on the right part of the window, i'm using v8.4.6 version.

Comment: Why did you copy/paste the other answer?